# SOCKET ERROR: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, smtp

I am using simple python lib for the SMTP 
But i am getting this error:

```
import smtplib
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 249, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 309, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 284, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Using python-2.7

Comment: the most simple - SMTP server not run at `localhost`

Comment: What is output of `netstat -lntp | grep 25`?

Comment: By default smtplib.SMTP attempts connection to port 25. There's currently apparently nothing listening on that port. If you want to run one the smtpd docs tell you how at http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtpd.html

Answer (score 20):

**Start a simple SMTP server with Python like so:**

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

**or you can also try gmail smtp setting**

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
```

Comment: Or install sendmail on localhost.

Answer (score 7):

if you:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

as suggested by Allen Thomas, then make sure you init:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(host='localhost', port=1025)
```

with matching port number, here: 1025.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Enable the Mode of Protocol you are using.Then it will create Bidirectional interaction virtual connection between your device and script.
For Example the following script will require Telnet Mode to be Enabled so that it can call to another Device he is requesting for.

telA = connect(a)

```
   telA.write("xcom Dial Number:43062@10.47.8.108\n")
   time.sleep(10)
   quit_telnet(telA)       
   print telA.read_all()
```